# Validating child form of a stepper component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React with material-ui.  I am using the stepper component to implement a checkout funnel for an ecommerce site:

```
              <React.Fragment>

                {getStepContent(activeStep)}

                <div className={classes.buttons}>
                  {
                  <Button onClick={handleNext} className={classes.button}>
                    {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Place order' : 'Next'}
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </React.Fragment>
```

getStepContent is defined as follows:

```
function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
  case 0:
    return <ShippingForm cart={cart}/>;
  case 1:
    return <AddressForm cart={cart}/>;
  case 2:
    return <PaymentForm cart={cart}/>;
  case 3:
    return <Review cart={cart}/>;
  default:
    throw new Error('Unknown step');
  }
}
```

I want to do some validation along the way, e.g., a user can't move past the Address form unless all the mandatory fields are filled in.  My problem is that the "Next" button sits outside of the "step" components.  I'm kind of new to React, but there appears to be no good way for the Next button's handleClick function to access the data in AddressForm component to do the validation, nor to kick off some validation function ni the AddressForm component.  What's the best way to do some validation when the Next button is clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got this!  I used React's ref capability.  In the main body of the component that renders the stepper, I declare a ref:

```
export default function Checkout(props) {
...
  let formRef = React.createRef();
...
}
```

In `getStepContent`, I pass the ref to the component I need to reference:

```
function getStepContent(step, cart, formRef) {
  switch (step) {
  ...
  case 1:
    return <AddressForm cart={cart} ref={formRef}/>;
  ...
  }
}
```

The AddressForm component has a validate() function.  In the `handleClick` function of the stepper's Next button, I call `formRef.current.validate()` to call the function.  Whew.

Comment: I'd be interested to see a bit more about how you accomplished this...

For me, `React.createRef()` creates a generic object with a type of `unknown` - so I'm not sure how you can get access to either the `current` or `validate()` functions on the inner component from that starting point?